# Cant write to files inside of .then()?

Tags: javascript, promise

I had a question about some code that i had working earlier, but now decides it doesnt want to work at all. Basically, I have a promise that returns me an array of data. I'll explain whats happening at the bottom of the code.

```
function mkdir(path){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        fs.mkdir(path, { recursive: true },function(err){
            if(err){console.log(err)}
        })
        return resolve()
    })
}
function writeFile(file,content){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        fs.writeFile(file, content, function(err){
            if(err){console.log(err)}
            return resolve()
        })
    })
}


function rawData(socket){
    var mintDataArray = []
    return new Promise(function(){
        for (let i = 1; i < 13; i+= 1) {
            getdat(i).then(function(r){
                //mintDataArray.push(r)
                for(o in r){
                    var dataurls = []
                    dataurls.push(r[o].discord_url,r[o].magic_eden_url,r[o].twitter_url)

                    //socket.emit('twitterFollowers',r[o])
                    const ProjectData = {
                        "mintDate": 0 || "",
                        "name":"",
                        "stock":0,
                        "links":[],
                        "mintTime": 0 || "",
                        "PricePlusDescription":0 || ""
                    }

                    if(r[o].mintDate != null){
                        ProjectData.mintDate = moment.utc(r[o].mintDate).format("MMMM Do")
                    }else{
                        ProjectData.mintDate = "No date specified yet"
                    }
                    

                    ProjectData.name = r[o].name
                    ProjectData.stock = r[o].supply
                    ProjectData.links.push(dataurls) 
                    ProjectData.PricePlusDescription = r[o].price
                    mintDataArray.push(ProjectData)

                }
                
                
            }).then(function(socket){
                //CollectionSorter(mintDataArray)
                for(i in mintDataArray){
                    var data = mintDataArray[i]
                    //console.log(data) // <----- This prints out the data that needs to be written to files.
                    var MintDateFolder = __dirname + "/UpcomingCollections/" +data.mintDate
            
                    if(!fs.existsSync(MintDateFolder)){
                        console.log('huh?')
                        mkdir(__dirname + '/UpcomingCollections/'+data.mintDate)
                    }
                    
                    writeFile(MintDateFolder +"/"+data.name,JSON.stringify(data))
                }


            })
        }
        //socket.emit('twitterFollowers',mintDataArray)
    })
}
```

So what the code is supposed to do, is check to see if that directory first exists in general. If it doesnt, then create the new directory. Then after that, its supposed to write files to it (not just that directory, but to other directories as well). It doesnt create the directory if it doesnt exists and it doesnt even write to it if i manually create the directory, however it does write to the other directories. I'm really not sure with this one because I had this working earlier, where it was creating the directory if it didn't exist. so i'm not sure what i messed up on.

I recently made mkdir and writefile functions and i thought they were the issue, because when i had this working I was just using fs.mkdir and fs.writefile. However, i went and tried again without those functions and i was still having the same troubles. I thought about making another promise to check if the directory existed but I already have quite a few nested promises.

read() function:

```
function read(i){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var r = https.request(options, function (res) {
            var data = []
            res.on('data', function (d) {
                data.push(d)
            }).on('end', function () {
                var NFTTokenData = []
                console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
                var info = Buffer.concat(data)
                zlib.gunzip(info,function(err,buf){
                    var NFTData = []
                    var x = buf.toString()
                    var dat = JSON.parse(x)
                    var collectionList = dat.pageProps.__APOLLO_STATE__
                    for(keys in collectionList){
                        if(collectionList[keys].__typename.includes('Nft')){
                            collections.push(collectionList[keys])
                            resolve(collections)
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                })
            
            })
        })
        r.end()
    })
}
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
function Project(fromApi) {
  return {
    mintDate: moment.utc(fromApi.mintDate).format("MMMM Do"),
    name: fromApi.name,
    imageLink:fromApi.project_image_link,
    stock: fromApi.supply,
    links: [
      fromApi.discord_url,
      fromApi.magic_eden_url,
      fromApi.twitter_url
    ],
    price: fromApi.price
  }
}

function write(project, dir) {
  const dest = resolve(dir, join(project.mintDate, project.name))
  console.log(dest)
  return stat(dirname(dest))
    .catch(_ => mkdir(dirname(dest), {recursive: true}))
    .then(_ => writeFile(dest, JSON.stringify(project)))
    .then(_ => project)
}

function rawData(socket){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17].map(i => 
      read(i).then(function(r){
      var data = []
      for(i in r){
        if(r[i].__typename == "Nft"){
          data.push(r[i])
        }
      }
      data.map(item => {
        var project = Project(item)
        write(project,"./UpcomingCollections")
      })

      })
    ) 
  })
}
```

This is a modification of the answer down below!

Comment: I have tried running your code it seems to be working fine on the local machine since I am using hardcoded data.
I can think of 2 issues here.
1. If you are only getting this issue on your deployment server and it's working fine on your local machine then it is probably permission issue you don't have permission to create new folder.
2. I have tried to refactor your code because .then after .then seems to be the issue I have refactored the code and can share with you and you can check if it's working.

Comment: https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#9n5m7f6f4loh6yv550kcq
I have refactored the code. Can you please try this I have tried it seems to be working on for me.
https://i.imgur.com/8P7Q8kS.png
https://i.imgur.com/a8V2rVF.png
Auto created all the files and folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do **anything** inside of `.then` – its only role is to *sequence* functions.

Let's talk about some other issues in your code -

```js
function mkdir(path){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        fs.mkdir(path, { recursive: true },function(err){
            if(err){console.log(err)} // ❌ reject(err); do not log
        })
        return resolve() // ❌ resolve() outside of mkdir callback
    })
}

function writeFile(file,content){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        fs.writeFile(file, content, function(err){
            if(err){console.log(err)} // ❌ reject(err); do not log
            return resolve() // ⚠️ "return" not needed
        })
    })
}
```

Did you find it tedious to implement wrappers for each `fs` function in Node? You will be happy to know the [fs/promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api) module already provides Promise-based APIs for each -

```js
import { mkdir, writeFile } from "fs/promises" // ✅

// mkdir(path[, options]) 
// Returns: <Promise> Upon success, fulfills with undefined if recursive is false, or the first directory path created if recursive is true.

// writeFile(file, data[, options])
// Returns: <Promise> Fulfills with undefined upon success.
```

Next we'll look over the other issues in the main program -

```js
function rawData(socket){
  var mintDataArray = [] // ⚠️ state "outside" of Promise context
  return new Promise(function(){
    for (let i = 1; i < 13; i+= 1) {
      getdat(i).then(function(r){
        for(o in r){ // ⚠️ global "o"; don't use for..in, use for..of instead
            // ,,,
            mintDataArray.push(Project) // ⚠️ attempting to send state "out" of Promise

        }
        // ⚠️ missing "return"
        // implicitly returning "undefined"
        
      }).then(function(socket){ // ⚠️ function parameter (socket) receives resolved Promise
        for(i in mintDataArray){ // ⚠️ global "i", for..in again, accessing external state
          var data = mintDataArray[i]
          var MintDateFolder = __dirname + "/UpcomingCollections/" +data.mintDate // ⚠️ use "path" module
  
          if(!fs.existsSync(MintDateFolder)){ // ⚠️ async methods until this point, why Sync here?
              console.log('huh?')
              mkdir(__dirname + '/UpcomingCollections/'+data.mintDate) // ⚠️ asynchronous
          }
          
          writeFile(MintDateFolder +"/"+data.name,JSON.stringify(data)) // ⚠️ attempts write before mkdir completes
        }
      })
    }
    socket.emit('twitterFollowers',mintDataArray) // ⚠️ accessing external state
  })
}
```

**read and transform data**

It's quite a bit of work, but don't worry. By breaking big problems down into small ones, we can work smarter, not harder. We'll start by renaming `getdat` to `read` -

```js
read(i).then(r => {
  const mintData = [] // state *inside* promise context
  for (const v of r) {
    // for all v of r, add project data to mintData
    mintData.push({
      mintDate: v.mintDate,
      name: v.name,
      stock: v.supply,
      links: [
        v.discord_url,
        v.magic_eden_url,
        v.twitter_url
      ],
      price: v.price
    })
  }
  return mintData // "return" resolves the promise
}).then(...)
```

Already our `.then` function is getting big. There's quite a bit of code for extracting and constructing the project data, so make that its own function, `Project` -

```js
function Project(fromApi) {
  // add date logic, or more
  return {
    mintDate: fromApi.mintDate,
    name: fromApi.name,
    stock: fromApi.supply,
    links: [
      fromApi.discord_url,
      fromApi.magic_eden_url,
      fromApi.twitter_url
    ],
    price: fromApi.price
  }
}
```

```js
read(i).then(r => {
    const mintData = []
    for (const v of r) {
      mintData.push(Project(v)) // ✅
    }
    return mintData
  }).then(...)
```

Which is the same thing as -

```js
read(i)
  .then(r => r.map(Project)) // ✨ no for loop needed!
  .then(...)
```

**write**

Let's check back in with your code and see our progress -

```js
function rawData(socket){
  // var mintDataArray = [] // ✅ remove external state
  return new Promise(function(){
    for (let i = 1; i < 13; i+= 1) {
      read(i)
        .then(r => r.map(Project)) // ✨
        .then(function(socket) {
          // ⚠️ remember, "socket" gets the resolved promise
          // since `read` resolves an array of Projects, we should rename it
        })
    }
    // ⚠️ we'll come back to this
    // socket.emit('twitterFollowers',mintDataArray)
  })
}
```

We continue with the `.then(function(socket){ ... })` handler. There's a good amount of code here for creating the path, making a directory, and writing JSON to a file. Let's make that its own function called `write` -

```js
import { stat, mkdir, writeFile } from "fs/promises"
import { join, resolve, dirname } from "path" //  unrelated to Promise "resolve"

function write(project, dir) {
  const dest = resolve(dir, join(project.mintDate, project.name)) // ✅ sanitary path handling
  return stat(dirname(dest))
    .catch(_ => mkdir(dirname(dest), {recursive: true})) // create dir if not exists
    .then(_ => writeFile(dest, JSON.stringify(project))) // write project JSON data
    .then(_ => project)                                  // return project
}
```

Our `rawData` function is cleaning up nicely, but we still have an outstanding issue of running async operations inside two separate loops -

```js
function rawData(socket){
  return new Promise(function(){
    for (let i = 1; i < 13; i+= 1) {
      read(i) //❓ how to resolve promise for each read?
        .then(r => r.map(Project))
        .then(projects => { // ✅ "projects", not "socket"
          for (const p of projects) {
            write(p, "./UpcomingCollections") //❓ how to resole promise for each write?
          }
          // ❓ what should we return?
        })
    }
    // socket.emit('twitterFollowers',mintDataArray)
  })
}
```

**promises in a loop**

Promise has another function we must become familiar with. `Promise.all` takes an array of promises and resolves only when *all* promises have resolved -

```js
function myfunc(x) {
  return Promise.resolve(x * 100)
}

Promise.all([myfunc(1), myfunc(2), myfunc(3)]).then(console.log)
// Promise{ [ 100, 200, 300 ] }

Promise.all([1,2,3].map(n => myfunc(n))).then(console.log)
// Promise{ [ 100, 200, 300 ] }
```

We can use `Promise.all` to clean up the two loops in `rawData`. And look at that, we can sequence the data directly into the `socket` -

```js
function rawData(socket){
  return Promise.all(
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(i => 
      read(i).then(r => r.map(Project))
    )
  )
  .then(projects => {
    Promise.all(projects.map(p => write(p, "./UpcomingCollections"))) // ✨
  })
  .then(projects => socket.emit("twitterFollowers", projects)) // ✨ 
}
```

**all together now**

We can see a lot of pain points are eliminated by using Promise-based code in an effective, idiomatic way. Until this point we have not addressed the issue of error handling, but now there's nothing left to say. Because we used Promises correctly, any errors will bubble up and the caller can `.catch` them and respond appropriately -

```js
import { stat, mkdir, writeFile } from "fs/promises"
import { join, resolve, dirname } from "path"

function Project(fromApi) {
  return {
    mintDate: fromApi.mintDate,
    name: fromApi.name,
    stock: fromApi.supply,
    links: [
      fromApi.discord_url,
      fromApi.magic_eden_url,
      fromApi.twitter_url
    ],
    price: fromApi.price
  }
}

function write(project, dir) {
  const dest = resolve(dir, join(project.mintDate, project.name))
  return stat(dirname(dest))
    .catch(_ => mkdir(dirname(dest), {recursive: true}))
    .then(_ => writeFile(dest, JSON.stringify(project)))
    .then(_ => project)
}

function rawData(socket){
  return Promise.all(
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(i => 
      read(i).then(r => r.map(Project))
    )
  )
  .then(projects => {
    Promise.all(projects.map(p => write(p, "./UpcomingCollections")))
  })
  .then(projects => socket.emit("twitterFollowers", projects))
}
```

**async..await**

Modern JavaScript provides `async..await` syntax allowing us to blur the lines between synchronous and asynchronous code. This allows us to remove many `.then` calls, flattens our code, reduces cognitive load, and shares asynchronous values in the same scope -

```js
async function rawData(socket) {
  const r = await Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(read))
  const projects = await Promise.all(
    r.flatMap(Project).map(p => write(p, "./UpcomingCollections"))
  )
  return socket.emit("twitterfollowers", projects)
}
```

Some of the complications of this program stems from the use of nested data. `Promise.all` is efficient and runs the promises in parallel, but keeping the data nested in the array makes it a bit harder to work with. To show that `async..await` truly blurs the line between sync and async, we will bring back the two `for..of` loops and call `await` in the loop. This results in a *serial* order processing but readability is terrific. Maybe your use-case isn't hyper demanding and so this style is completely adequate -

```js
async function rawData(socket) {
  for (const i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]) {
    const result = await read(i)
    for (const r of result) {
      const project = Project(r)
      await write(project, "./UpcomingCollections")
      socket.emit("twitterFollowers", project)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very detailed and thorough answer. Its always a good feeling when someone replies and you can actually learn something from what they said. Thank you, you made promises a little easier. and honestly, i had no clue about mapping until now.

Comment: One thing i did have a question though, i havent used much of es6, just really getting into js here. that led me to learn that i couldn't use require anymore, and had to switch to import which was hard to use with some modules. Im not sure what is causing it, but its causing the read function to break. I updated my code with the read function at the bottom, i took out part of the https request to save space. What would be causing this? and should i just try using .map instead of for in once again?

Comment: I'm happy you were able to learn something :) `import` is the new standard, but you can still use `require` in NodeJS. `import { foo, bar } from "mymodule"` is roughly equivalent to `const { foo, bar } = require("mymodule")`. Many examples here: [ES2020 import](https://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html)

Comment: I'll try to review the `read` code later today

Comment: Ahh nice I see. Yeah i was confused because you cant use import and require in the same file without getting an error (because you need to do type:"module" in the package json) but thats easily fixable.

Comment: and thank you, i just woke i'm about to test around with .map and try and understand more how it works with what im doing.

Comment: Got it working, in my other function i just turned the for(keys in collections) into a map. after that i was able to get it working, thanks for showing me about maps! I'm going to update my post with the final solution

Answer (score 1):

Mulan's answer was correct, I just needed to change the for loop in my other function, to a .map. After that, everything worked perfectly. I had to do some modification to the rawData function as seen below.

```
function Project(fromApi) {
  return {
    mintDate: moment.utc(fromApi.mintDate).format("MMMM Do"),
    name: fromApi.name,
    imageLink:fromApi.project_image_link,
    stock: fromApi.supply,
    links: [
      fromApi.discord_url,
      fromApi.magic_eden_url,
      fromApi.twitter_url
    ],
    price: fromApi.price
  }
}

function write(project, dir) {
  const dest = resolve(dir, join(project.mintDate, project.name))
  console.log(dest)
  return stat(dirname(dest))
    .catch(_ => mkdir(dirname(dest), {recursive: true}))
    .then(_ => writeFile(dest, JSON.stringify(project)))
    .then(_ => project)
}

function rawData(socket){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17].map(i => 
      read(i).then(function(r){
      var data = []
      for(i in r){
        if(r[i].__typename == "Nft"){
          data.push(r[i])
        }
      }
      data.map(item => {
        var project = Project(item)
        write(project,"./UpcomingCollections")
      })

      })
    ) 
  })
}
```